# How to combine two Unicode symbols to create a new symbol?

Tags: unicode

I want to create a new symbol that combines an "Latin small letter o" and the diacritic symbol for "low line."

Latin small letter o is U+006F

Diacritic low line is U+0332.

The desired result would have a line below the o. It is the opposite of "Latin capital letter O with Macron" (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/014c/index.htm)  except that the line is equal to the width of the 0.

**How to combine `U+006F` and `U+0332` for use with JSON (e.g. `\u006F` and `\u0332)` and for use with HTML `hex` (e.g. `&#x6F;` and `&#x332;)`**

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224772/whats-the-unicode-glyph-used-to-indicate-combining-characters?rq=1 which explains HTML e.g. &#x6F;&#x332; I need a longer 'low line' but will find one. Not sure how to do this for JSON.

Comment: Type a letter o, then type a combining low line? No code needed, just paste o̲. How it actually looks is completely dependent on the font you're rendering it in.

Comment: I opened a Python REPL and wrote `"\u006F\u0332"` and copied the result: o̲

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this quesion: [What's the unicode glyph used to indicate combining characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224772/whats-the-unicode-glyph-used-to-indicate-combining-characters?rq=1)

the answer for HTML and JSON basically is the same: concatenate sans space.

HTML entities: `&#x6F;&#x332;`

JSON: `\u006F\u0332`